# Single radiobutton in groupbox can be deselected

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to search corresponding topics but I couldn't find any so here I am.
I have created an application in Python and PyQt4 where I can import some data from a file. During the import I create dynamically some groupboxes and radiobuttons in them for the user to display the desired data. It can happen that a groupbox has only one radiobutton in it because of the collected data.

The problem is that when the user click on this already-selected-all-alone radiobutton, it is being deselected (no black dot in the middle). Clicking once more on it select it again...

Is it a bug or should I set a property so this behavior doesn't happen (meaning the button is never deselected because it is alone in the groupbox)?

How can I prevent this behavior?

## Example (added)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.resize(289, 171)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("GroupBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setAutoExclusive(True)
        self.radioButton.setText("RadioButton")
        self.gridLayoutRb = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayoutRb.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0,0,1,1)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('cleanlooks'))
    window = MyApp()
    out_msg = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(out_msg)
```

Comment: It's certainly not a bug. The normal way to deal with this is to simply disable the button. That way, it's clear to the user that the button's state cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ekhumoro suggested it is possible to disable the radiobutton because there is only one button. The downside is that the button and its text is greyed. If it isn't a problem then it is a solution.

An other ways is to permanently add a radionbutton in the groupBox and then set its coordinates (by changing its properties to negative values) to put it outside the groupBox. This is **only** possible when **NOT USING LAYOUTS**.